# Trying to find a map, of the London underground/tube which shows where lines run underground vs overground

Tags: qgis, raster, mapping

I'm trying to find a map, of the London underground/tube which shows where lines run underground vs overground.

Seems a bit of a tricky one to find as when including the word overground in Google its coming up with maps including the overground system with the underground, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Format can be just a raster image or a GIS format for bonus points!

Comment: Have you checked with OSM?

Comment: I haven't, I'll have a look there for GIS formats, thanks. I have already found a raster format and posted as answer for others

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more searching I have found a non-gis format on the official TFL site!

https://content.tfl.gov.uk/tube-map-with-tunnels.pdf

Comment: A fun fact, 45% of the underground is in tunnels :)